# Empty Masked Edit control returning mask for text

Tags: vb6, maskedtextbox

I have a simple form with a couple of fields that are optional - FirstName, LastName, SSN and DOB. The user either has the option of entering a value or leaving it empty. I'm seeing a problem with my DOB maskedtextbox. Initially, if the user doesn't input a DOB, it gets saved as null. Later on, the user has the option of editing the DOB. The problem I'm seeing is that, if on EDIT the user doesn't enter any value in DOB, the system writes the change to "##/##/####" which is my mask. SO when I run an edit, and the user changes First and Last Names only, leaving DOB empty, I get an error saying "Conversion failed when converting date/time from string. " I'm not sure if I should convert the mask "##/##/####" to Null before I insert the edits? This is my statement in case the value for DOB changes. If it does it writes the change to the Table. I have similar statement for all the other fields and everything works great.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.mskDOB.Text) And Me.mskDOB.Text <> "" Then
      If IIf(IsNull(g_RS!DOB), "", g_RS!DOB) <> Me.mskDOB.Text Then
      g_strSQL2 = g_strSQL2 & " DOB = '" & Me.mskDOB.Text & "',"
End If
```

Comment: You might take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve There just isn't a lot of information here.

Answer (score 0):

The MaskedEdit control has a [`PromptInclude`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227874(v=vs.60).aspx) property which says:

> Specifies whether prompt characters are contained in the Text property value.

Setting this property to `False` will allow you to test the `Text` property to see if it's empty (equal to "").